# Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard with Kotlin

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, kotlin

I'm trying to write a simple Android app in Kotlin. I have an EditText and a Button in my layout. After writing in the edit field and clicking on the Button, I want to hide the virtual keyboard.

There is a **popular question** [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard) about doing it in Java, but as far as I understand, there should be an alternative version for Kotlin. How should I do it?

Answer (score 228):

Use the following utility functions within your Activities, Fragments to hide the soft keyboard.

**(*)Update for the latest Kotlin version**

```
fun Fragment.hideKeyboard() {
    view?.let { activity?.hideKeyboard(it) }
}

fun Activity.hideKeyboard() {
    hideKeyboard(currentFocus ?: View(this))
}

fun Context.hideKeyboard(view: View) {
    val inputMethodManager = getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
}
```

This will close the keyboard regardless of your code either in dialog fragment and/or activity etc.

**Usage in Activity/Fragment:**

```
hideKeyboard()
```

Comment: Where would you recommend these three functions live in the application?

Comment: @Dan I keep these functions in ContextExtensions.kt file of mine but you can keep them anywhere you find suitable.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Funny thing is I only needed this code when the app was running on a physical device. On the simulator (AVD) the keyboard dismissed itself like a good keyboard does.

Comment: For some reason when I put these in a ContextExtensions.kt file, I can't seem to access them from my Fragments, etc..  Is there something special I need to setup in the ContextExtensions class in order to make these accessible across the app?

Comment: @svguerin3 It should work directly. Only thing that I can think of is that if you're using multi module android project I'm not so sure if you can access Kotlin Extensions which is defined in another module. But also try to clean/rebuild.

Comment: For Activity: hideKeyboard(currentFocus ?: View(this))

Comment: @CeH9 Yeah, shorter is better

Comment: OMG thanks SO much for this. Coming from iOS, it seems ridiculous to me that this is even a problem but your solution is the cleanest I've seen. Thank you!

Comment: not able to use these in functions, any help regarding their calling ?

Comment: They need to be called using an activity, fragment, or context reference if you're not directly calling them inside fragment or activity.

Answer (score 89):

I think we can improve [Viktor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41791472/7487335) a little. Based on it always being attached to a `View`, there will be context, and if there is context then there is `InputMethodManager`:

```
fun View.hideKeyboard() {
    val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
}
```

In this case the context automatically means the context of the view.
What do you think?

Comment: i want to add this method in one utility class , then how to call this method from activity/fragment/adapter ??

Comment: well use for example `editText.hideKeybord()` editText can be replaced with any view.

Comment: Is there a way to put this in a separate class so that it's accessible throughout the app?

Answer (score 24):

Simply override this method in your activity. It will automatically works in its child fragments as well.....

**In JAVA**

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (getCurrentFocus() != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

**In Kotlin**

```
override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        if (currentFocus != null) {
            val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(currentFocus!!.windowToken, 0)
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
    }
```

Answer (score 15):

In your Activity or Fragment create a function as:

```
fun View.hideKeyboard() {
 val inputManager = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
      inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
}
```

suppose you have a button with an id `your_button_id` in XML file related to this Activity or Fragment, so, on button click event:

```
    your_button_id.setOnClickListener{
       it.hideKeyboard()
     }
```

Comment: Simple and accurate

Answer (score 8):

Peter's solution solves neatly the problem by extending functionality of View class. Alternative approach could be to extend functionality of Activity class and thus bind operation of hiding keyboard with View's container rather than View itself.

```
fun Activity.hideKeyboard() {
    val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(findViewById(android.R.id.content).getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I didn't see this variant of Kotlin extension function:

```
fun View.hideSoftInput() {
    val inputMethodManager = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
}
```

Its benefit is that this extension function could be called from every CustomView and in every click or touch listener

Answer (score 6):

Make an object class named Utils:

```
object Utils {

    fun hideSoftKeyBoard(context: Context, view: View) {
        try {
            val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            imm?.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    }
}
```

You can use this method in any class where you want to hide the soft input keyboard. I am using this in my `BaseActivity`.

Here the view is any view that you use in your layout:

```
Utils.hideSoftKeyBoard(this@BaseActivity, view )
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use Anko to make life easier, so the line would be:

```
inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
```

or maybe better to create extension function:

```
fun View.hideKeyboard(inputMethodManager: InputMethodManager) {
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
}
```

and call it like this:

```
view?.hideKeyboard(activity.inputMethodManager)
```

Comment: which Anko lib we have to use ? because it's not working with me

Comment: inputMethodManager is not founded

Answer (score 5):

Although there are many answers but this answer is related to a best practice in **KOTLIN** by opening and closing the keyboard with life cycle and extension function.

**1). Create Extension Functions** create a file *EditTextExtension.kt* and paste the below code

```
fun EditText.showKeyboard(
 ) {
  requestFocus()
  val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as 
  InputMethodManager
  imm.showSoftInput(this, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
 }

fun EditText.hideKeyboard(
) {
 val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as 
 InputMethodManager
 imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.windowToken, 0)
 }
```

**2). Create LifeCycleObserver Class** Create a class *EditTextKeyboardLifecycleObserver.kt* and paste the code below

```
class EditTextKeyboardLifecycleObserver(
 private val editText: WeakReference<EditText>
 ) :
 LifecycleObserver {

 @OnLifecycleEvent(
     Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME
 )
 fun openKeyboard() {
     editText.get()?.postDelayed({ editText.get()?.showKeyboard() }, 50)
 }
 fun hideKeyboard() {
     editText.get()?.postDelayed({ editText.get()?.hideKeyboard() }, 50)
 }
}
```

**3).** Then use the below code in **onViewCreated / onCreateView**

```
lifecycle.addObserver(
         EditTextKeyboardLifecycleObserver(
             WeakReference(mEditText) //mEditText is the object(EditText)
         )
     )
```

The Keyboard will open when the user opens the fragment or activity.

if you occur any problems, following the solution feel free to ask in the comment.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer that worked for me here:  http://programminget.blogspot.com/2017/08/how-to-close-android-soft-keyboard.html

```
val inputManager:InputMethodManager = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(currentFocus.windowToken, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution in Kotlin for Fragment. Place it inside `setOnClickListener` of the button.

```
val imm = context?.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager?
imm?.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

This works well with API 26.

```
val view: View = if (currentFocus == null) View(this) else currentFocus
val inputMethodManager = getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Write a function to hide the keyboard:

```
private fun hideKeyboard(){
        // since our app extends AppCompatActivity, it has access to context
        val imm=getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        // we have to tell hide the keyboard from what. inorder to do is we have to pass window token
        // all of our views,like message, name, button have access to same window token. since u have button
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(button.windowToken, 0)

       // if you are using binding object
       // imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(binding.button.windowToken,0)

    }
```

You have to call this function whereever u need

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Zeeshan Ayaz
Here is a little improved version

Because 'currentFocus' is nullable we better check it using Kotlin's ?.let

```
override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    currentFocus?.let { currFocus ->
        val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(currFocus.windowToken, 0)
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello I frequently use these two extension functions for showing and hiding soft keyword.

1. Show Soft Keyboard

   ```
   fun Any.showSoftKeyboard(view: View, context: Context) {
     if (view.requestFocus()) {
         val imm: InputMethodManager =
         context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as 
   InputMethodManager
        imm.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
      }
   }
   ```
2. Hide Soft Keyboard

   ```
   fun Any.hideSoftKeyboard(view: View, context: Context) {
         val imm =
         context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as 
   InputMethodManager
       imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
   }
   ```

You can use these methods in any Object Class to access these globally or you can make separate Extensions/CommonUtils Files for these.

Answer (score 0):

You can use from bellow code, I write bellow code in my fragment:

```
private val myLayout = ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
    yourTextView.isCursorVisible = KeyboardTool.isSoftKeyboardShown(myRelativeLayout.rootView)
}
```

Then in `onViewCreated` of `fragment`:

```
......
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
myRelativeLayout.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(myLayout)
......
```

And in `onDestroyView` use too:

```
override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
 myRelativeLayout.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(myLayout)
}
```

And:

```
object KeyboardTool {
    fun isSoftKeyboardShown(rootView: View): Boolean {
        val softKeyboardHeight = 100
        val rect = Rect()

        rootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect)

        val dm = rootView.resources.displayMetrics
        val heightDiff = rootView.bottom - rect.bottom
        return heightDiff > softKeyboardHeight * dm.density
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin
I use bellow code:

import splitties.systemservices.inputMethodManager

inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view?.windowToken, 0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Function Extension in Kotlin. Replace activity by fragment if you need make it in Fragment.

```
fun Activity.hideKeyboard() {
    hideKeyboard(currentFocus ?: View(this))
}
```