# Android close keyboard by pressing 'done' called from a SearchView inside an AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-softkeyboard, searchview

From a Fragment, I am using a SearchView inside an AlertDialog and I would like the keyboard's 'Done' button to dismiss the keyboard. For some reason it is not working.

Here is my AlertDialog"

```
val mBuilder =
        AlertDialog.Builder(context!!, Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_NoActionBar_Fullscreen)
val mView = View.inflate(activity!!, R.layout.list_search, null)
mBuilder.setView(mView)
val dialog = mBuilder.create()
val searchView = view.findViewById<SearchView>(R.id.search_view)
dialog.show()

searchView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)

searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
    override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
        adapterWithSearch.filter(newText)
        return true
    }

    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
        adapterWithSearch.filter(query)
        return true
    }
})
```

And here is my SearchView:

```
<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    style="@style/AppTheme.Searches"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

I would like the keyboard to be dismissed, not the AlertDialog. 
Anyone has an idea of why the keyboard isn't being dismissed?

Comment: You want to dismiss the keyboard or the dialog?

Comment: you want that if you press done the keyboard swipe down become invisible?

Comment: I want the keyboard to be dismissed, not the AlertDialog

Comment: I edited, Is the searchView a `SearchView` object? in the case you have a generic view, or I gave a link to another post where `SearchView` is a proper` SearchView ` component

Comment: You'd add a call to hide the keyboard in the onQueryTextSubmit function.  Your current code isn't doing that.  If you search for "close keyboard android" you'll find dozen of old questions

Answer (score 0):

Probably I am not seeing correctly what you are trying to do but I can not see where are you trying to dismiss the keyboard. For this action you have two alternatives:

Try to see this and hope it is helpful

[Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard with Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41790357/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard-with-kotlin)

You have here different ways to dismiss a keyboard. I don't see more complexity in this question.

Also I found this --> 
[How to dismiss keyboard in Android SearchView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409288/how-to-dismiss-keyboard-in-android-searchview)