# EditText field never gets submitted

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I got a `RecyclerView` with multiple `EditText`-fields. When I try to edit one of the `EditText`-fields and click enter on the virtual keyboard, the focus shifts down to the next `EditText`-field, something I don't want to happen. I want to submit the changes I made in the first `EditText`-field and then close the keyboard. I managed to turn off this focus-shifting by adding the following to my .xml file:

```
  android:focusable="true"
  android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

But the problem still persists, now the changes just never get submitted as my listener never gets called. If I remove all items except from one in my `RecyclerView` everything works like I want. How can I make that happen with more items in my`RecyclerView` too?

My `bind` function inside my `UserCardItem.kt` file;

```
 override fun bind(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
...
  viewHolder.itemView.creditcard_nickname.setOnEditorActionListener{ _, actionId, _ ->
            if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
                saveNickname(viewHolder)
                true
            } else {
                false
            }
        }
```

```
    private fun saveNickname(viewHolder : ViewHolder){
        val nickname = viewHolder.itemView.creditcard_nickname.text.toString()
        userCreditcard.nickname = nickname
        UserCardStore().updateNickname(userCreditcard)
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add the code of your listener and the code related to your submit functionality?

Comment: @MuddassirAhmed I have added the code related now. Thank you for showing interest

Comment: Can you try adding this to your EditText?

`android:imeOptions="actionDone"`

Comment: Cool. Can you accept my answer?

Comment: @Done. Do you know why the keyboard isn't hidden on `actionDone`?

Comment: Not sure. You can do that through some code though. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41790357/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard-with-kotlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` to your EditText in your layout XML.