# How to perform auto click

Tags: android, kotlin

how to auto click a Edit_Text?

we have search field and when the user clicks, we go to search intent where Edit_Text is available, but after the user has clicked, we don't want him to click repeat just do it once
I mean we have a Edit_Text and to type input first we have to click on the Edit_Text so I don't want to wait for the user to click
When the activity will start I want keyboard directly to open

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set Focus on EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327412/set-focus-on-edittext)

Comment: Not quite understand your demand. Can you explain more specifically?

Comment: fallow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65178221/10148810) keyboard will open automatically with the EditText when user will move to the activity or fragment